# Regular Expression in R -Dynamically remove first and last character

Tags: r, regex, character-encoding

I have a character table in R and I'd like to remove the first and last 
     characters. I tried using the sub function but it only works for X1 and not 
     X2. Basically I want to go from this

```
   X1       |       X2
-----------|--------------
 N40ø47.30'|  W111ø58.67'
 W32ø50.83'|  E96ø51.11'
```

I'd like to get something like  this

```
  X1           X2
----------|------------
40ø47.30  |  111ø58.67
32ø50.83  |  96ø51.11
```

Comment: How did you use `sub`?

Comment: DF$X1 <- sub('.','',DF$X1)

Comment: You may do a similar thing with X2. See http://ideone.com/WzKjjA

Comment: it doesn't work . I am trying to remove the first letter and apostrophe at the end.

Comment: Really? Check the *stdout* in http://ideone.com/WzKjjA again. The output is exactly as you showed in the question.

Comment: After running your code, it goes from this N40ø47.30'
W111ø58.67    to   40ø47.30'   W111ø58.67

Comment: It does not make much sense, please post the real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character is `^.`, the last is `.$`,
you can use `gsub` to remove both at the same time:

```
DF$X1 <- gsub('^.|.$', '', DF$X1)
```

Another alternative, without regular expressions is to extract the middle part of the string:

```
substr(DF$X1, 2, nchar(as.character(DF$X1)) - 1)
```

However, note that these solutions only work for values that have at least two characters. It's possible to make the `gsub` solution work for single-character values:

```
gsub('^.(.*).$', '\\1', DF$X1)  # thanks for @wiktor-stribiżew
```

Comment: Actually, this `'^.|.$'` will remove a 1- and 2-char strings. Not sure what OP needs here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point, added a note about that limitation

Comment: Yeah, but as per OP feedback, `gsub('^.(.*).$', '\\1', DF$X1)` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

IT is not what you asked, but if you only want to remove the characters N,E,S,W and ' you could run:

```
gsub("N|E|S|W|'","",DF)
```